# vba function to return record with most recent date. given another criteria

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I need to set the default value for a textbox in an ms access 2010 form.  The default value needs to be the most recent date in `CommunicationTable` where the `ClientNumber` is the same as the `ClientNumber` associated with the current record in the form.  The code below references the correct `ClientNumber`, but I am not sure how to get the most recent date.  I am concerned that `DMax` might not be the appropriate function for getting the most recent date.  How should I change the following to get the most recent date?

```
=DMax("DateOfCommunication","[CommunicationTable]","[ClientNumber]=  "  
& [Forms]![Main]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![ClientNumber] & "")
```

I realize I should also post the larger function in which the above function is nested:

```
=DLookUp("[Level]","[CommunicationTable]","DateOfCommunication= "  
& DMax("DateOfCommunication","[CommunicationTable]","[ClientNumber]=  "  
& [Forms]![Main]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![ClientNumber] & ""))
```

Also, the form itself is bound to `CommunicationTable`.  This VBA function is in the `DefaultValue` dialog box, which I get into via the property sheet for the text box.  So I am not sure that creating a sql query will work in this case.

---

### EDIT:

I have uploaded a stripped down copy of the database which reproduces the problem  [at this file sharing site](http://jmp.sh/v/6X79HFZXoBMMlfU2c6x3).

To locate the code:

```
1.) Open the CommunicationEntryForm and  
2.) open the AfterUpdate() event procedure for the ClientNumber field.
```

Next, to reproduce the problem:

```
1.) close `CommunicationEntryForm`    
2.) In the Main form(which should already be open), click the View tab to open  
    the most recent CommunicationForm for any Client you want.  Note the Level  
    number for that Communication.  
3.) Click on the Communication tab.  This will leave the form and show a list  
    of CommunicationForms for that Client.  
4.) Click the Create New Form button.  This will open up CommunicationEntryForm.  
    The value for Level should be the same as the value you noted in step 1 above.  
    The problem is that this is blank.
```

Can someone show me how to fix this problem?

Comment: Why use the default value property like that if you want to customize the value anyway?

Comment: @HansUp Sounds like you are saying that my code is correct.  But it is not passing validation tests on real data.  Is there a problem in my syntax?  Do I need to add `##` somewhere?  What should I change?

Comment: @craig.white How else do you suggest that I set things up?  The form itself is bound to an underlying data table. I want the field to have the most recent preceding value for that field from that `ClientNumber`.  If you have a suggestion, can you put it in code?

Comment: @HansUp I do not know how to check the value returned by `DMax()`. But the problem is that the `DLookUp()` expression does not reliably return the record with the most recent date among that `ClientNumber`'s records in the table. There is no error, just unreliable data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@CodeMed - I did download the database but found you have issues other than what you are describing- such as when you 'add' a new communication you simply overwrite an existing record.  I managed to get the result you were looking for, but it just changes the 3 records around.  Does your non-sample program actually have the ability to create and add new records?  As it is, I just changed your existing code to this:

```
Private Sub cmdNewCommForm_Click()
Dim cNum As Long
Dim strSQL As String
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb
cNum = Forms!Main!NavigationSubform.Form!ClientNumber
strSQL = "SELECT Top 1 Co.Level AS MaxOfLevel " & _
         "FROM CommunicationTable co Where Co.ClientNumber = " & cNum
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
Forms!Main!NavigationSubform.Form!NavigationSubform.SourceObject = "CommunicationEntryForm"
Forms!Main!NavigationSubform.Form!NavigationSubform!ClientNumber = cNum
Forms!Main!NavigationSubform.Form!NavigationSubform!DateOfCommunication = Date
If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
    Forms!Main!NavigationSubform.Form!NavigationSubform!Level = rs!MaxOfLevel
Else
    Forms!Main!NavigationSubform.Form!NavigationSubform!Level = 0
End If

Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is first grab the date by doing something like:

```
Dim db as Database
Dim rec as Recordset

Set db = CurrentDB
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT Top 1 DateOfCommunication FROM CommunicationTable WHERE ClientNumber= " & [Forms]![Main]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![ClientNumber] & " ORDER BY DateOfCommunication DESC")
```

This will get the most recent date.  Then, in your above VBA, you can just stick rec(0) in where your calculation was:

```
Me.MyDateField = DLookUp("[Level]","[CommunicationTable]","DateOfCommunication= #" & rec(0) & "#")
```

Substitute "MyDateField" with whatever that name of your date field actually is.

I'm pretty sure you need the pound signs (or "hashtags" as the kids call them today...) in order for Access to do the calculation on a date value.

Comment: +1 for trying to help. In the `property sheet` for the `txtLevel` textbox, the `Default Value` field in the `Data` tab has the `DLookUp()` expression. So where do you suggest that I put the `Database` and `RecordSet` code that you suggested in your answer?  Which event handler?  For which object?

Comment: You can put that block of code in the AfterUpdate event of ClientNumber, probably?  Whatever the last piece of relevant info entered into the form, put it in the AfterUpdate event of that textbox/dropdown/whatever control it uses.

Comment: Access says your `DLookUp` expression contains an invalid string.  Something to do with the location of the quotation marks.  Any suggestions?

Comment: First of all, set Me.MyDateField = DLookup.  In other words, put "Me.MyDateField" to the left of that DLookup string, substituting your actual date field's name.  Also, I think I left off a double-quote after the last # in my formula.  I'm going to edit the above so it makes sense.

Comment: I uploaded a stripped down version of the database to a file sharing site and I added an edit to my original posting above with instructions for reproducing the problem. Can you please look at it and explain what needs to change? That might be a lot faster than trading a lot of messages without looking at the database.

Comment: Now I'm confused- when you first described your problem you were trying to get the most recent date.  According to your upload and last edit you are trying to get a 'Level' value'.  If this is the case we need to know what 'Level' is for to best help- if it's a Client setting then it should go into the Client table.  If it's the number of communications than it is completely different.  If it's something else, well, we just need to know.

Comment: @craig.white `Level` is a variable that the user enters manually during each communication.  Might as well call the variable `HasMonkey` or any other arbitrary variable name. The original post above asks how to retrieve the row that has 1) the given `ClientNumber` and 2) The most recent `date`. `Level` is just the name of one of the fields in the row. Are you please willing to recreate the problem in the uploaded file using the instructions in the post and show me how to fix the problem?

Comment: @JohnnyBones Are you willing to take a look at the sample database I uploaded and help me find the problem so that your code works?